# Bing GeocodeServiceClient requires 2 parameters

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I have added the SOAP services to my C# project and created a small application around it to test bing out. Everything is fine except the GeocodeServiceClient. From every example I've found, the following is fine

```
var geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
```

However, when I come to build, I'm finding that I need two parameters for the GeocodeServiceClient. Delving further, it seems that the base class needs the second parameter

```
public GeocodeServiceClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
        : base(GeocodeServiceClient.GetBindingForEndpoint(endpointConfiguration), GeocodeServiceClient.GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
    }
```

What is this second parameter that I need to pass in?

For completeness, here is the code I'm using

```
    void GeocodeAddress(string address)
    {
        var geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest
        {
            Credentials = new Credentials
            {
                ApplicationId = App.Self.APIKEY,
            },
            Query = address,
            Address = new Address()
        };

        var filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter();
        filters[0].MinimumConfidence = Confidence.High;

        var geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions
        {
            Filters = new ObservableCollection<FilterBase>(filters)
        };
        geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

        var geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");

        var myLoc = new Location();

        geocodeService.GeocodeCompleted += async (object sender, GeocodeCompletedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                if (e.Result.Results.Length > 0)
                if (e.Result.Results[0].Locations.Length > 0)
                {
                    myLoc = e.Result.Results[0].Locations[0];
                    var uri = await Map.GetMapUri(myLoc.Latitude, myLoc.Longitude, 2, "HYBRID", 300, 300);

                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Map(uri));
                }
            }
        };

        geocodeService.GeocodeAsync(geocodeRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the legacy Bing Maps SOAP services. They are old, slow and haven't been updated in years. The documentation for this service isn't even online anymore. This service was replaced by the Bing Maps REST service 5 years ago. You can find information on the Bing Maps REST services here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

You can find documentation on using these services in .NET here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

Comment: Thanks - bit of a pain that, need to recode part of my legacy code now :(

Comment: If you want to continue using the SOAP services look in the web.config file and you will find two endpoints for the SOAP service. one will be a basic one and the other a custom one. Remove the custom one. You should then be able to create the geocode service client without specifying an endpoint configuration.

Comment: Thanks - I'd rather not have to recode if I don't need to. Just waiting for the Here API to become available again... :)